# I can't connect raspberry pi and sensor by USB

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, usb, pyusb

I connect raspberry Pi(CM3+) with sensor by USB.
I download and install pyusb.
I write the followig python codes.But, error massage appear.
I wonder if you could give me advices.

codes

```
import usb.core
import usb.util

# find our device
dev = usb.core.find(idVendor=0x0403, idProduct=0x6001)

# was it found?
if dev is None:
    raise ValueError('Device not found')

# set the active configuration. With no arguments, the first
# configuration will be the active one
dev.set_configuration()

# get an endpoint instance
cfg = dev.get_active_configuration()
intf = cfg[(0,0)]

ep = usb.util.find_descriptor(
    intf,
    # match the first OUT endpoint
    custom_match = \
    lambda e: \
        usb.util.endpoint_direction(e.bEndpointAddress) == \
        usb.util.ENDPOINT_OUT)

assert ep is not None

# write the data
ep.write('test')
```

error

```
raise USBError(_strerror(ret), ret, _libusb_errno[ret])
   usb.core.USBError: [Errno 16] Resource busy
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1.**  :: Try to Reset the kernel using

```
dev.reset()
```

**Solution 2** :: Detach if any devices previously attached that are cached using

```
if dev.is_kernel_driver_active(0):
    reattach = True
    dev.detach_kernel_driver(0)
```

Comment: Thank you, Mr. Bhargav. My problem is solved.

Comment: Yeah, Can you upvote? If it helps. Thank you